# how to get the response on next.js middleware , after nextresponse.next()

Tags: next.js

i have some code like below , how can i read the route.ts reponses in middleware?

### middleware.ts

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse} from "next/server";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
    let response = await NextResponse.next({ request: request });   //--->route into route.ts
        console.log(response.body)  // expect "{a:123}"
    return response;
}
export const config = { matcher: "/:path*" };
```

### app/route.ts

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest} from "next/server";
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
     return NextResponse.json({a:123});

}
```